# ConfigurationManager ConnectionString not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this project I am working on and I want to "hide" my connection string from my main class and place it to the App.Config.

While trying to access the connection string from the main class I get this error "`System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.this[string].get returned null.`"

This is my main class code that I use to get the conn string:

```
string ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
```

This is my App.Config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Password=XXXX;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=XXXX;Initial Catalog=XXXX;Data Source=XXXX"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Note: I have to add the app.config by myself as a new class.
Also the connection string works perfect when it's in the main class, so it's not its fault.

Comment: I don't understand, in the first paragraph you say it doesn't work in main, but then you say it only works in main. (?) In any case please provide your main code or where do you get it.

Comment: I never said it's not working when it **is** in the main class, I said it doesn't work when I try to **access** or **call** it from the main class. I get it when I call it, see "this is my main class ... " part of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConnectionString null after reading from app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388740/connectionstring-null-after-reading-from-app-config)

Comment: Check if `app.config` is present in the bin folder. If not - right click on the config file and select "Build Action" - "Content" in options.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli, nope :(

Comment: @GuruStron It's there but Build Action was set to none, set it to "Content" but still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WebConfig connection string should be like this:

```xml
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS" connectionString="server=.;database=MVCCrud;integrated security=SSPI" providerName="Sql.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The main class connection string should be like this:

```cs
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I am missing something here.   How this is different from what the OP posted?  Is it that the `<connectionStrings>` section is not a subsection of the `<configuration>` section?

Answer (score 0):

I added config, added you code and configuration and it worked.

I can't add this as a comment, as I can't post images there, that's why I am writing an answer.

So, just to make sure you added the file in a correct way:

right click your project, add -> new item:

[image]

and then just find appropriate file to add (you can make use of search text box):

[image]

Comment: This is exactly how I created it but I can't read anything from it. It either returns null as a value or throws an error.